# Derivative of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification, absolute-value, differential

I want to check whether if my way is correct or not, and why?

\begin{align*}
f'(x)&=\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\right)'\\
&=\dfrac{-\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)'}{\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)^{2}}=\dfrac{-\left(\dfrac{(x-1)'}{2\sqrt{x-1}}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)^{2}}\\
&=\dfrac{-\left(\dfrac{(x)'-(1)'}{2\sqrt{x-1}}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)^{2}}=\dfrac{-\left(\dfrac{1-0}{2\sqrt{x-1}}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)^{2}}=\dfrac{-\left(\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x-1}}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)^{2}}\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{(x-1)}\left(\sqrt{x-1}\right)^{2}}=-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{(x-1)}|x-1|}\\
&=\boxed{-\dfrac{1}{2\left(x-1\right)\sqrt{(x-1)}}}
\end{align*}

Comment: Are you familiar with the chain rule? You could do the derivation in one step by the chain rule.

Comment: I am but one of my student give me this

Comment: The result looks good to me, but I think you missed copying the 2 from deriving $\sqrt{x-1}$ onwards until it suddenly appears. As a matter of taste I like $\sqrt{x-1}^3$ more than $(x-1)\sqrt{x-1}$.

Comment: Should I say to him that I like $\sqrt{x-1}^{3}$ more than $(x-1)\sqrt{x-1}$ How can I convince him?

Comment: I don't quite understand $(\sqrt{x-1})^2=\lvert x-1\rvert$, since the actual identity would be $(\sqrt{x-1})^2=x-1$. In a sense, the assertion $(\sqrt{x-1})^2=\lvert x-1\rvert$ not falsifiable in the real variable, because $x-1=\lvert x-1\rvert $ is necessary for $\sqrt{x-1}$ to exist, but it looks like poor understanding of the identities $(\sqrt{x-1})^2=x-1$ and $\sqrt{(x-1)^2}=\lvert x-1\rvert$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\left((x-1)^{-1/2}\right)'=-\frac 12(x-1)^{-3/2}$ and this is over.

I think pushing up doing $(x-1)'=1$ step by step is really *too much*.

Also derivating composition of functions $\frac 1\cdot\circ\sqrt{\cdot}$ is not necessary, go directly with the derivative of $x^\alpha$ in this case. But I admit that considering an highschool level, this may be the only available choice (since fractional exponents may be out of scope).

The point is that when facing more complex functions, the risk of getting confused will increase if one is not familiar with shortcuts. Also the more stuff you write, the more chance a typo WILL occur and ruin it all.

I would keep only terms 1, 2, 3, 7 and 10 (1 being f'(x)) from your calculation, and explain intermediate steps orally if necessary.